# Java seeds on bedrock

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been noticing that there are a lot of really cool Java edition seeds on Minecraft. However, I am currently playing only bedrock edition and I don’t have access to those worlds. I was wondering if there was a way to translate Java seeds to bedrock. I have seen it done before, and it was a little confusing... does anyone know of a way to translate these seeds? Thanks!

Comment: I don't feel like writing out a full answer, but perhaps check this link
https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-load-Minecraft-Java-edition-seeds-in-Bedrock#:~:text=There%20is%20a%20converter%20software,it%20to%20the%20Bedrock%20Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually depends on the type of java seed some java seeds are unable to switch to bedrock no matter what you do. If the java seed has a minus sign(-) you can't convert it if it doesn't have a minus sign you can convert it. What you need to do to convert java seeds that don't have minus signs is to subtract 4294967296 from the java seed number and use the number that you get after subtracting on your bedrock world. Hope this helps!

Comment: Here is a link for how to do it https://www.sportskeeda.com/minecraft/how-convert-minecraft-bedrock-seed-java-seed

Comment: Also, this comment is from my old account. Also, with the 1.19 update, all terrain and biomes from java will be playable on bedrock (and vice versa) but for now, only about one four billionth of all java seeds are version compatible, but all bedrock seeds are version compatible with java.